# webpack multiple output path, limit public access, or custom index.html?

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack-2, typescript2.0, html-webpack-plugin

I am using node-express, with typescript.

my folder is setup as follows:

```
.dist
  public
    public.js
    index.html
  server.js
node_modules
src
  classes
    namespace1
      module1
  public
    app - all angular files. 
    main.ts
  routes
    index.ts
  app.ts
package.json
tsconfig.json
webpack.config.js
```

Now, I need webpack to output 2 files to `/public/public.js` and `/server.js` at `.dist` folder. nodejs will then run from `.dist/server.js`, and I want to separate `public.js` to prevent client to access `server.js`
I also use `html-webpack-plugin` to generate html files.

I have tried using a little hack like

```
entry: {
  "server": "./src/app.ts",
  "public/public": "./src/public/main.ts"
}
```

but then html-webpack-plugin made `index.html` to load script from `/public/public.js` instead of `public.js`

Now, I think we can solve this in 3 way.

1. Let server.js send public.js using `http://localhost/public.js`, but it will make managing static folder a little bit complicated. but I will think some way to trick it. **Question:** how to serve `public.js` via `server.js`?
2. Set entry to `"public": "./src/public/main.ts"`. **Question:** how to put that public.js into public folder?
3. Setup `html-webpack-plugin` to load from `/public.js` instead of `/public/public.js` and make `index.html` inside `/public` folder. As of now, `html-webpack-plugin` generates `<script type="text/javascript" src="../public/polyfill.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="../public/public.js"></script></body>` where is should make `<script type="text/javascript" src="/polyfill.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/public.js"></script></body>`

   **Question:** How to do that?

Or is there any other idea to solve this? I am open to any suggestion.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed by using this config.

```
module.exports = [
    {
        entry: "./src/app.ts",
        output: {
            filename: "server.js",
            path: __dirname + "/dist"
        },
        target: "node",
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.tsx', '.jsx']
        },
        node: {
            __dirname: false
        },
        module: { // all modules here for server
        }
    }, {
        entry: "./src/public/main.ts",
        output: {
            filename: "bundle.js",
            path: __dirname + "/dist/public"
        },
        target: "web",
        plugins: [
            new htmlPlugin({
                filename: 'index.html'
            })
        ],
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.tsx', '.jsx']
        },
        module: { // all your modules here. 
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I can answer scenarios 2 and 3.

2- Apart of setting up entry points, you can set up some output configuration. http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output

3- Also you could use copy webpack plugin to copy the files you need into your public folder.
https://github.com/kevlened/copy-webpack-plugin

I do it in one of my projects, this is the code that I add on the webpack config file:

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin([
    {from: __dirname + '/src/public'}
  ])
```

Hope this helps.

Regards.

Comment: That's pretty interesting.. Ok.. suppose I add entry as `{server: 'app.ts', public: 'public/main.ts'}` then create output `{filename: '[name].js', path: __dirname + '/.dist'}`. How do I put `path: __dirname + '/.dist/public'` only for `public.js`?

Comment: Based on the official documentation It's not possible having 2 different entry points and a single output. Why would you want having different entry points and one single output? I think that's against what a module bundle is, right ? It's about the concept and I think that's why it's not implemented on that way.

Comment: I need 2 outputs, in 2 different folders. One in main folder, one in public folder. If I put `filename: [name].js`, then I will get `server.js` and `public.js`. I want to get `server.js` and `public/public.js`, and `public/index.html`

Comment: Did you take a look to copy webpack plugin to do that ? 
new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        {from: __dirname + '/server.js', to: 'whereveryouneed'},
        {from: __dirname + '/public/public.js', to: 'whereveryouneed'},
      ])

__dirname variable might be not needed in your case. That depends on your folder structure.

Comment: Yes.. I got this error. Seems it can't locate and copy some of generated files. So copy plugins for generated files seems hit and miss. ERROR in [copy-webpack-plugin] unable to locate 'dist/index.html' at 'Y:\skeleton-webpack\dist\index.html'

Comment: After I read your answer again, I think you understood my question wrong. I didn't ask on how to copy files into public folder. Please read my question again. I asked, how to make html-webpack-plugin links bundles from `public.js` instead of `/public/public.js`. Or, to put simply, remove `public` root path from generated `html-webpack-plugin` files. Not to copy them to `public` folder, as it is already in `public` folder. The problem is that `html-webpack-plugin` generated <link> tag as if it is loaded from root.

Comment: Also, I cannot copy anything inside my `/src/public` into `/.dist/public` as they are in typescript, and need to be transpiled by webpack before copied to `/.dist/public`. ALL FILES in `/.dist` are generated by webpack.